# How can I filter a pandas dataset based on multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am trying some ifthen logic but I am working in a dataframe and couldn't find any examples.

What I am trying to do is filter this dataset to only include values where 
col1=col3 and col2=col4

```
col1       col2     col3       col4
Wagner     John     Wagner     John
Jane       Mary     Klein      Peter 
Schneider  Megan    Wicker     Sam
Schneider  Megan    Schneider  Megan
```

result

```
col1       col2     col3        col4
Wagner     John     Wagner      John
Schneider  Megan    Schneider   Megan
```

My code here doesn't work

```
 df1.apply(lambda x : x['col1'] if x['col1'] == x['col1'] and x['col2'] == x['col2'] else "", axis=1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use [DataFrame.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental) method:

```
In [205]: df.query("col1==col3 and col2==col4")
Out[205]:
        col1   col2       col3   col4
0     Wagner   John     Wagner   John
3  Schneider  Megan  Schneider  Megan
```

or a "classical" approach:

```
In [206]: df.loc[(df.col1==df.col3) & (df.col2==df.col4)]
Out[206]:
        col1   col2       col3   col4
0     Wagner   John     Wagner   John
3  Schneider  Megan  Schneider  Megan
```

Comment: I tired and got an error ValueError: cannot assign without a target object

Comment: @OptimusPrime, are you talking about first or second method?

Comment: @OptimusPrime, make sure that you use `==` instead of `=`

Comment: how come I get different results when I do df.loc[(df.col1==df.col3) & (df.col2==df.col4)] vs df.loc[(df.col1==df.col3)  df.loc[(df.col2==df.col4)]

Comment: @OptimusPrime, , i didn't get your second line of code: `df.loc[(df.col1==df.col3) df.loc[(df.col2==df.col4)]`

Comment: it seems like the when doing df.loc[(df.col1==df.col3) & (df.col2==df.col4)] the loc seems to have had some issues.  I had to run the code separately in two lines

Comment: `df.loc[(df.col1==df.col3) & (df.col2==df.col4)]` should work fine. If you have spaces in column names: `df.loc[(df['col1']==df['col3']) & (df['col2']==df['col4'])]`

Answer (score 1):

messing around with `numpy` and assuming the columns are the specific order they are

```
df[np.equal(*df.values.T.reshape(2, 2, -1)).all(0)]

        col1   col2       col3   col4
0     Wagner   John     Wagner   John
3  Schneider  Megan  Schneider  Megan
```

---

If columns were in another order

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
v = np.column_stack([df[c].values for c in cols])
df[np.equal(*v.T.reshape(2, 2, -1)).all(0)]
```